# Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined when I load my pages

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-chrome-extension

I am editing a codeIgniter application purchased online which have no support, everything is OK but javascript codes are not working, it keeps giving this error message

`Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at w.g.P (chrome-extension://ngpampappnmepgilojfohadhhmbhlaek/content.js:22:354)
    at w.g.na (chrome-extension://ngpampappnmepgilojfohadhhmbhlaek/content.js:4:214)`

and when continue viewing the page it says

`content.js:21 Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
    at w.g.ka (content.js:21)`

But actually in my directories I don't see the page named `content.js`

How can I solve this error? and finally have my javascript functions working?
Thank you.

Comment: ngpampappnmepgilojfohadhhmbhlaek is an id of [IDM](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idm-integration-module/ngpampappnmepgilojfohadhhmbhlaek) so it's not related to codeIgniter.

Comment: Ohh!, thank you, how comes IDM interact with this application? confused!

Comment: Extensions can run their content scripts on any web page.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm, I have uninstalled IDM and the error has gone, but now nothing is displayed from javascript even simple function of `alert()` is not working

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) I doubt this is answerable. You can use devtools to debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for contribution, I came to realize that problem was on my script arrangement, JavaScript had to start at the top of the page, so my problem solved by uninstalling IDM plugin from chrome and re-arranging the script.